# Why doesn't Apache POI correctly evaluate Boolean functions?

Tags: java, excel, boolean, apache-poi

I have Java code that uses Apache POI 5.2.2. The program works fine, except that Apache POI does not evaluate Excel Boolean functions correctly. For example, I have an Excel file called “eje.xlsm” that looks like this:

[image: code image]

It only has the formula `AND(A1="a";B1=0)` in cell C1 and the values "a" in A1 and 1 in B1. The main function of my Java program reads this information and changes the value in B1 to 0, so that C1 should change to TRUE:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("./eje.xlsm"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(2).getBooleanCellValue());
        sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).setCellValue(0);
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(2));
        System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(2).getBooleanCellValue());
        FileOutputStream  out =  new FileOutputStream("./eje.xlsm");
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        workbook.close();
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I was expecting this output on the console:

```
false
true
```

But, instead, I get:

```
false
false
```

I do not know why. I have tried to reconfigure Apache POI in Eclipse, which I use for Java coding, but the problem persists. It only happens with Boolean functions, so with other functions it works fine.

Comment: The problem is the `+` before the `AND` in your formula. Why is it there? Do using the formula without that `+` and it will work.

Comment: Axel, thank you very much. I didn't have noticed that +, nor have ever thought it was a problem, but you are right. Without the + it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in your screenshot, the formula in your Excel sheet is `=+AND(A1="a";B1=0)`. The `+` before the `AND` is superfluous.

The `+` in that formula does the following:
Evaluation of `AND(A1="a";B1=0)` results in either boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  But `+TRUE` and/or `+FALSE` converts the boolean to numeric. `+TRUE` = `1` and `+FALSE`  = `0`.

You will see this if you do the following in your code:

```
...
sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).setCellValue(0);
CellType cellType = evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(2));
System.out.println(cellType); //NUMERIC
...
```

Excel itself ignores the superfluous `+` while evaluating the formula and remains the boolean type. But Apache POI does not. One could call this a bug, as Apache POI tries to act exactly like Excel. But the simplest solution is not to use that superfluous `+` in Excel formulas.